# error C2062 when compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

first I want to say that i'm totally a noob in C or C++. I'm trying to understand how compiling works, how the language works etc. This time I've been looking for a solution for many hours before posting here. I hope you will be able to help me, even if it appears to be a very easy findable solution.

Here it is.

I'm trying to nmake a makefile.Win32 file and I got these errors :

```
e:\progs\c\vanitygen-master\winglue.h(47) : error C2062: type 'char' unexpected
e:\progs\c\vanitygen-master\winglue.h(47) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
e:\progs\c\vanitygen-master\winglue.h(47) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : code retour '0x2'
Stop.
```

Here is the winglue.h file (--> points the line 47)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>

#define INLINE
#define snprintf _snprintf

struct timezone;

extern int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
extern void timeradd(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b,
         struct timeval *result);
extern void timersub(struct timeval *a, struct timeval *b,
         struct timeval *result);

extern TCHAR *optarg;
extern int optind;

extern int getopt(int argc, TCHAR *argv[], TCHAR *optstring);

extern int count_processors(void);

#define PRSIZET "I"

static inline char *
/* --> */ strtok_r(char *strToken, const char *strDelimit, char **context) {
return strtok_s(strToken, strDelimit, context);
}

#endif /* !defined (__VG_WINGLUE_H__) */
```

I hope you guys will help me !
I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express on a Win 7 64bits computer.

Edit : If it helps to know it, I'm running a brand new installation of the software.

Comment: Looks like a stupid redefinition of `char` through a macro or such. Did you try the `TCHAR` type instead?

Comment: Yes. I tried with tchar, int and others types. I've tried even without any type. Didn't help. 
Thanks for looking at it !

Comment: Have you done any modifications to the source?

Comment: I've edited the makefile.Win32 only to add path of the differents tools the programm needs.

Comment: Side note: You might install an English version

Comment: @DieterLücking yes probably. I will edit my post to add english translation, then install an english version.

Comment: "...only to add path of the differents tools .." *what tools*? just curious. Were any of those mods modifying the include paths ?

Comment: Divide and conquer - remove (comment) code and see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is to make it a define, you are calling a different function with the same parameters in the same order, returning the result.

But as to the cause of your problem, its probalbly a stupid define in `<windows.h>`, it has alot of defines it shouldnt. Im guessing its inline. try `__inline__` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will do some research in this direction. However changing `inline` into `__inline__` didn't help.

Comment: if you just want a quick fix, change the whole function defenition to #define strtok_r strtok_s